# onlyOwner / onlyProvable with oracle functions using Provable

Tags: oracles, provable

Is it possible to make a function `onyOwner`, since one of them must obviously be called by Provable's server? Or is there an equivalent modifier to it, such as `onlyProvable`?
If not, would there be a way to code one?

More generally, what about making functions `internal` or `private`?

Comment: And how exactly would the Provable's server call a private or internal function??? Even the owner wouldn't be able to do that.

Comment: Since there are several functions at stake (between the initializer, the callback and the function that's executed), my question was for each of these functions: I don't understand which one is called by the server, and therefore which one must be `public`.
Also, if this function that should be `public` actually must be, calling it from another `function otherFunction() public` should, I believe, lift that need. Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: Perhaps the real question I might have would be... Is there a `onlyProvable` modifier somewhere? Or is it possible to write it? How do we know which is the address of the Provable server that will call our function, and is it always the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The __callback() function actually does that in one of their [example](https://github.com/provable-things/ethereum-examples/blob/052ce8186df4b907bf3cddd0858c19dc054ac320/solidity/KrakenPriceTicker.sol#L26).

The Provable's server address can be accessed through `provable_cbAddress()`, defined in the Provable imported file. Therefore, a modifier could be written like this:

```
modifier onlyProvable() {
    require(msg.sender != provable_cbAddress(), "The sender is not Provable's server.");
    _;
}
```